# Share from Native app to webapp

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

My Chrome Progressive-Web-App(running on an android phone) needs to receive an Share intent from a native app.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Refer from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190446/share-functionality-for-mobile-web-apps): `If your web app is wrapped in a native layer (via Phonegap or by manually creating the native layer yourself), you can communicate your intention to share to the native layer by various means (like providing a url with a custom protocol that only your native layer intercepts, or via javascript callback functions) and delegate the share intent to your native layer.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard way to do that at the moment, but there is already a proposed Web API to do exactly that, and it's called the [**Web Share Target API**](https://github.com/WICG/web-share-target). Definitely something worth looking forward to.

Comment: Thank you, I hope this API gets implemented soon in all major browsers.